# Adjust Navigation Bar width inside NavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xamarin.ios

[image: My table layout]

I am trying to implement a horizontal scrolling table view. I was able to accomplish this with the following layout. I have a `ScrollView` which contains a `Container View` which points to my `NavigationController`. Since I made the `Container View` wider than the `ScrollView`, the table is able to scroll left to right as expected.

The problem I am having is resizing the `Navigation Bar`'s width as I **do not want** to have to scroll to view the `Navigation Bar`'s title. I tried explicitly setting the width property of the `Navigation Bar` in `ViewDidAppear` however it keeps getting resized to the actual width of the table view. Is there any way I can do this without having to create my own custom view that mimics that `Navigation Bar`?

Comment: I'm afraid so ,you need a custom view that mimics that Navigation Bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own navigation bar that is placed on top of the actual integrated table view navigation bar.